# Publication on Step Completion?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-6.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We've written a custom Gazebo (6.5.1) plugin so that we can single-step through time.  That is, we start `gazebo -u` paused and then proceed through time step-by-step.  A step is taken each time our plugin receives an external message to take a step.

Currently, we wait to receive a `WorldStats` publication from gazebo to consider a step completed.  However, it appears these messages may be sent at regular time intervals, regardless of the step having completed.

Does Gazebo published a message that's more suitable to knowing that the step has been completed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12881/publication-on-step-completion?/) by [xanderai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2517/xanderai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a command line program that you could use:

`gz world -s`

In your plugin you can compare the `iterations` value to see if a step has occurred.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xanderai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2517/xanderai/) on 2016-04-05**:
Thanks.  We were able to simplify our situation by either not caring about the `WorldStats` message and carrying on as usual, or have some guarantees by having the plugin deal with `iterations` value.